# Adding double precision values yield different results between separate programs in C++

Tags: c++, precision, addition, floating-accuracy

I have a question about floating point addition. I understand how compilers and processor architecture can lead to floating point arithmetic values. I have seen many questions on here similar to my question, but they all have some variation such as different compiler, different code, different machine, etc. However, I'm am running into an issue when adding doubles in the ***exact*** same way in two different programs calling the ***identical*** function with the same arguments and it is leading to different results. Both programs are compiled on the same machine with the same compiler/tags. The code looks similar to this:

```
void function(double tx, double ty, double tz){

    double answer;
    double x,y;

    x = y = answer = 0;

    x = tx - ty;
    y = ty - tz;

    answer = (tx + ty + tz) * (x*y)
}
```

The values of:

```
tx,ty,tz
```

are on the order of [10e-15,10e-30]. Obviously this is a very simplified version of the functions I am actually using, but, is it possible for two programs, running identical floating point arithmetic (not just the same function, the exact same code), on the same machine, with the same compiler/tags, to get different results for the function?

Comment: What *is* different between the programs, such that you’re calling them different programs instead of different runs of the same program?

Comment: What's the difference, if they are identical? Why do you call them two programs then?

Comment: The answer is that you're not being completely truthful and the programs aren't identical. The specific function you're referring to might be, but the programs themselves are not. Computers are deterministic. So there must be a difference.

Comment: The similarity ends with this specific function call. They are two different programs that are calling the same mathematical formula. I have coded both of these formulas exactly the same in each program. The values that are being printed out are from the arithmetic done inside of this function (the values don't go somewhere else in the program and get returned for example).

Comment: Print out a hex dump of the inputs to the function before calling it. They may not be as identical as you think. Also, compilers aggressively inline things these days, so your function may actually never really be called, it may be dispersed into the code that calls it and therefor the execution path through the function be different resulting in different rounding errors.

Comment: Where do the values come from in each program? Are they the same code as in you copy-pasted that function into multiple files, or are you including a header file with this function defined inline, or are you linking against the same library which contains this function? If it’s the last one, do you have link-time optimization (`-flto`) enabled?

Comment: Please put here the exact code, with exact (binary) inputs/output you got in both cases.

Comment: Do you have `-ffast-math` or (equivalent) enabled?

Comment: Given what you've said about the two programs, there's no obvious reason for **this calculation** to be done differently. That means that your two programs are calling the function with **different values**.

Comment: One obvious possible difference is whether `x` and/or `y` are passed through memory before being multiplied or kept in floating point registers the whole time. Storing and retrieving through memory may result in a loss of precision and inline may affect whether they pass through memory.

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities:

1. The source code of `function` is identical in the two programs, but it appears with different context, resulting in the compiler compiling it in different ways. For example, the compiler might inline it in one place and not another, and inlining might lead to some expression reduction due to combination with other expressions at the point of the inlined call, and hence different arithmetic is performed. (To test this, move `function` to a separate source file, compile it separately, and link it with a linker without cross-module optimization. Also, try compiling with optimization disabled.)
2. You think there are identical inputs to `function` because they appear the same when printed or viewed in the debugger, but they are actually different due to small differences in the low digits that are not printed. (To test this, print the full values using the hexadecimal floating-point format. To do that, insert `std::hexfloat` into the output stream, followed by floating-point values. Alternately, use a C `printf` using the `%a` format.)
3. Something else in the programs changes floating-point state, such as rounding mode.
4. You think you have used an identical compiler, identical sources, identical compilation switches, and so on, but actually have not.

[David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) notes that floating-point values can change when they are stored, as occurs when they are simply spilled to the stack. This occurs because some processors and C++ implementations may store floating-point values with extended precision in registers but less precision in memory. Technically, this fits into either 1. (different computation nominally inside `function`) or 2. (different values passed to `function`), but it is insidious enough to warrant separate mention.

Comment: Given the lack of information and response from the OP this is an excellent answer. It answers the real question: "I'm at my wits end here, how the heck do I debug this problem?".

Comment: @Omnifarious The debug process is pretty simple. If one of the answers is unreasonable, investigate that one specifically. If both answers are reasonable, then figure out why this is causing you pain because all you're supposed to expect are reasonable answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is quite easy. If your computer behaves **deterministic** it will always return the same results for the same input. That's the basic idea behind programming languages so far. (Unless we are talking about quantum computers, of course.)

So the question reduces to whether you really have **the same input**.

Although the above function looks strictly functional, there are often **hidden inputs** that are not that obvious. E.g. you might adjust the rounding mode of your FPU before calling the function. Or you might setup different exception behavior. In both cases the function may behave differently for certain inputs.

So even if your computer isn't non-deterministic (i.e. buggy) the above function *might* return different results. Although it is not that likely.

Comment: More likely would be different inlining behavior; the compiler can do floating-point math differently at compile time and run time. That’s why I asked about LTO above.

Comment: In other words: the code may be the same, but the settings or other "environmental" factors are not necessarily the same.